2019: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
  -- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Bitcoin over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         35
Users destroyed³                                140          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue           148        528
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                9         36
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         42        257
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               46        287
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue               170      1,665
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue              248      1,034
Tags merged                                      23          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            16          0
Tag synonyms created                             16          0
Questions reopened                                9          0
Questions protected                               0        119
Questions migrated                               10          1
Questions flagged⁵                               26      1,599
Questions closed                                749        311
Question flags handled⁵                         658        967
Posts unlocked                                    0          4
Posts undeleted                                  12         39
Posts locked                                      8        338
Posts deleted⁶                                  921      2,609
Posts bumped                                      0      2,883
Comments undeleted                                7          0
Comments flagged                                  0        508
Comments deleted⁷                               229        932
Comment flags handled                            79        429
Answers flagged                                  43      2,637
Answer flags handled                          1,842        836
All comments on a post moved to chat              5          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Bitcoin without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).   
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: 2018: a year in moderation...
You can also check out this report on other sites
Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites

Wishing you all a happy new year...
